# flat a laravel collection by a specific index

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a a collection like this :

```
Collection {#447
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "1"
      "row" => "1"
      "size_x" => "2"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "1"
    ]
    1 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "3"
      "row" => "1"
      "size_x" => "1"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "11"
    ]
    2 => array:6 [
      "pos" => "0"
      "col" => "1"
      "row" => "2"
      "size_x" => "2"
      "size_y" => "1"
      "cat_id" => "10"
    ]
]
}
```

Now I want an array like this that get only `cat_id` indexes.

```
[1,11,10]
```

How can I do that in laravel ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do that. The easiest is to use the `pluck` method:

```
$collection->pluck('cat_id');
```

This will return a new Collection. If you want to convert it to an array just use `toArray()` or `all()` afterwards:

```
$items = $collection->pluck('cat_id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection->pluck("cat_id")->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pluck` method and pass field name as an argument:

```
$new_collection = $your_collection->pluck('cat_id');
```